# Как надо объявлять и инициализировать глобальную `char *` константу в Си и С++?

Tags: c, c++, linux

Ситуация следующая.

Есть функция (в отдельном файле), поведение которой зависит 
от внешней переменной. Эта функция должна вызываться как из программ, в которых 
устанавливается значение этой переменной, так и программ, которые об этой 
переменной ничего не знают (и знать не хотят).

Скажу сразу, что если функция оттранслирована gcc -c, то проблем нет. С ней
нормально работают любые как C, так и C++ программы.

Просто попробовал скомпилировать ее C++ (естественно, будет работать только
с C++ программами) и возникла проблема:

```
  ext-p.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `extext'
  /tmp/ccLZRaiS.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Вот файлы:

```
// ext.h
extern const char *extext;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int ptext (const char *t);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Этот заголовочный файл включается во все программы, вызывающие `ptext()`.

```
// ext-p.c та самая внешняя функция
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ext.h"

const char *extext;

int ptext (const char *p) {
  return puts (p ? : extext ? : "nothing to print");
}
```

Тут дело в том, что если внешний модуль не использует extext, то ее значение
будет NULL.

Пара программ, вызывающих функцию

```
// ext-mc.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ext.h"

#ifndef __cplusplus
const char *extext = "text test";
#else
const char *extext = "c++ text test";
#endif

int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  ptext(av[1]);
}
```

ext-mc.c устанавливает значение `etext`, а следующая ничего о нем и знать не хочет.

```
// ext-m.c    
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ext.h"

int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
  ptext(av[1]);
}
```

Протокол компиляции и запуска

```
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ gcc ext-p.c -c
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ g++ ext-mc.c ext-p.o
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ ./a.out 
c++ text test
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ gcc ext-mc.c ext-p.o
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ ./a.out 
text test
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ g++ ext-m.c ext-p.o
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ ./a.out 
nothing to print
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ gcc ext-m.c ext-p.o
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ ./a.out 
nothing to print
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$
```

Видно, что когда файл с `ptext()` оттранслирован `gcc` все работает, как задумано.

```
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ g++ ext-p.c -c
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ g++ ext-m.c ext-p.o
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ ./a.out 
nothing to print
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ g++ ext-mc.c ext-p.o
ext-p.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `extext'
/tmp/ccLZRaiS.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
avp@avp-xub11:avparse$
```

Собственно, вопрос тот же, что и в заголовке -- **Кто-нибудь знает, как запрограммировать такую штуку**, что бы все можно было 
компилировать и gcc и g++?

**Update 1**

Судя по предложениям в некоторых комментариях наверное в вопросе я недостаточно осветил проблему.

Есть функция (вообще-то не та, что приведена в примере), которая используется во многих программах и не вызывается напрямую из main. Она выводит содержимое некой структуры (один из ее параметров).

Желательно, чтобы дополнительную информацию (константный для программы текст -- автор, версия и т.п.) не нужно было "тащить" от main(), где она естественным образом определена до этой функции.

Если функция оттранслирована gcc и лежит в библиотеке, то все ОК. Проблем ни с Си, ни с С++ программами и способом задания в них этой информации (можно как в примере в вопросе, а можно просто в начале main написать extext = "bla-bla.." или даже прочесть из конфига и т.п.).

Если же программист берет файл .c с ней и собирает программу (g++) вместе с другими своими .cpp файлами и в Makefile явно не прописывает, что ее надо компилировать gcc -c, то возникает описанная ошибка.

Вопрос, **а это вообще реализуется в С++** остается.

**Update 2** (смотрю, [@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg) появился)

Сейчас мы видим такую картину:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ gcc -c ext-p.c; nm ext-p.o
0000000000000008 C extext
0000000000000000 T ptext
                 U puts
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$ g++ -c ext-p.c; nm ext-p.o
0000000000000000 B extext
0000000000000000 T ptext
                 U puts
avp@avp-ubu1:avparse$
```

Может быть решение получится, если ответить на такой вопрос:

**Как надо писать `ext-p.c`**, что бы в выводе `nm ext-p.o` вместо `B extext` получить `C extext`?

Comment: что то я не вижу, что бы ext.h имел guard'ы.

Comment: @KoVadim, понятно же, что это минимизированный пример.

Comment: Скорее всего вы уже этот вариант знаете и он вам не подходит, но рискну предложить: а чем #define extext не устраивает, если все равно константы?

Comment: @MDJHD, ну, `#define` тут совсем ни при чем.

Наверное в вопросе я недостаточно осветил проблему.

Есть функция (вообще-то не та, что приведена в примере), которая используется во многих программах и не вызывается напрямую из `main`. Она выводит содержимое некой структуры (один из ее параметров). 

Желательно, чтобы дополнительную информацию (константный для программы текст -- автор, версия и т.п.) не нужно было "тащить" от `main()`, где она естественным образом определена до этой функции.

--

(места мало, продолжу в след. комменте)

Comment: (продолжение)

Если функция оттранслирована gcc и лежит в библиотеке, то все ОК. Проблем ни с Си, ни с С++ программами и способом задания в них этой информации (можно как в примере в вопросе, а можно просто в начале `main` написать `extext = "bla-bla.."` или даже прочесть из конфига и т.п.).

Если же программист берет файл .c с ней и собирает программу (g++) вместе с другими своими .cpp файлами и в Makefile явно не прописывает, что ее надо компилировать gcc -c, то возникает описанная ошибка.

--

Вот почему `#define` (все равно он никак не попадает в текст этой функции) не решает проблему.

Comment: Ладно, а почему бы не собирать ext-p.c компилятором C всегда? По-моему вполне нормальное решение. На всякий случай можно поставить препроцессорную проверку, что файл собирается именно компилятором C, а не C++.

Comment: @dzhioev, и это очевидное решение. Впрочем, я что-то писал на эту тему в первом **Update** вопроса.

Ну, представьте, человек берет все исходники, пишет Makefile, указывает там `CC = g++`, запускает и ...

После этого он, конечно, все понимает и легко достигает желаемого результата.

Он либо просто присваивает значение `extext` (на самом деле там много подобных переменных) в какой-нибудь функции, либо пишет в Makefile gcc для ext-p.c (и м.б. еще нескольких фйлов).

--

Но, если можно писать так, чтобы подобных проблем не возникало, то почему бы не попытаться понять, как это стоит сделать?

Comment: @avp, С и С++ разные ЯП, так что если разработчик пытается компилировать C файлы компилятором C++, то это его проблемы.

Answer (score 6):

Вот это:

```
const char *extext = "text test";
```

не установка значения, а определение с инициализацией. Получается у вас переменная `extext` определена и в ext-p.c, и в ext-mc.c. Правильным будет убрать лишние определения из ext-mc.c, и устанавливать `extext` где-нибудь в main:

```
// ext-mc.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ext.h"

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{    
#ifndef __cplusplus
  extext = "text test";
#else
  extext = "c++ text test";
#endif

  int rc = ptext(av[1]);

  return printf ("ptext: %d\n", rc) < 0;
}
```

**UPD**:
В С++ можно инициализировать глобалы результатом произвольного выражения. Поэтому можно сделать как-то так:

```
bool initialized = (extext = "text");

int main() {
  ... 
}
```

Можно так:

```
class GlobalInitialization {
    GlobalInitialization() {
      extext = "text";
    }
    static GlobalInitialization instance_;
};

GlobalInitialization GlobalInitialization::instance_;

int main() {
  ...
}
```

Но в C оба эти способа работать не будут.

Comment: @dzhioev, это очевидный способ. 

Хотелось бы в виде определения с инициализацией (вне тела функции, точнее *перед* `main()`). 

Естественно, инициализация допустима только в одном месте загрузочного модуля.

Т.е. как в Си.

В крестах это в принципе возможно?

Comment: @avp, прочитал вопрос внимательней. Я если честно не могу понять, почему у вас `g++ ext-mc.c ext-p.o` и `g++ ext-mc.c ext-p.o` не падают в первых двух случаях. По идее при линковке должна быть ошибка, т.к. ext-p.o и объектник полученный из ext-mc.c будут иметь одноименные символы.

Comment: @avp, тогда стоит убрать определение extext из ext-p.c, но это будет *обязывать* определять extext в каком-либо другом модуле.

Comment: @dzhioev, не совсем понял о каких 2-х первых случаях Вы говорите.

Вообще имеем мы следующее:

    gcc -c ext-p.c ext-mc.c; nm ext-p.o ext-mc.o
    ext-p.o:
    00000004 C extext
    ....
    ext-mc.o:
    00000000 D extext
    ....
    
    g++ -c ext-p.c ext-mc.c; nm ext-p.o ext-mc.o
    ext-p.o:
    00000000 B extext
    ....
    ext-mc.o:
    00000000 D extext
    ....

Видите типы у внешнего символа `extext` разные. Тип **C** это Common секция. 

(подробнее, например, в `man nm`).

Rjhjxt? djghjc -- f rfr hf,jnfnm c dytiybvb cbvdjkfvb d rhtcnf[& -- jcnftncz/

Comment: @avp, понятно, не знал, что есть такой механизм. А почему вы против инициализации внешнего extext в main? Ваш способ выглядит странно.

Comment: @dzhioev, потому, что в таком случае, 

если в `main` нет `extext`, в `ext.h` есть только `extern const char *extext;`, а в `ptext()` в `ext-p.c` есть обращение к `extext`, то программа попросту не соберется

     avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ gcc ext-m.c ext-p.o
     ext-p.o: In function `ptext':
     ext-p.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `extext'
     collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
     avp@avp-xub11:avparse$ 


Я же вроде все пожелания к использованию `ptext()` расписал в вопросе.

Цель как раз состоит в том, что программы, которым не нужен `extext` и не должны его определять.

Comment: А если инициализировать extext в NULL в ext-p.c?

Comment: Вот. Тут комментарии закончились. Приходится удалять, чтобы новый добавить.

-- старый

@paulgri, я сделал Update ответа, проясняющий ситуацию.

--

@dzhioev, в Си ничего не изменится. Неинициализированный явно Common  инициализируется 0-ми.  

И как видим с С++

    g++ ext-p.c -c; nm ext-p.o
    00000000 B extext

остается то же самое.

Answer (score 4):

Если используются сугубо ГНУтые компиляторы, то почему бы не ослабить ([в компоновочном смысле](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol)) определение `extext` в `ext-p.c`:

```
const char *extext __attribute__((weak));
```

Тогда и плюсовый компилятор выдаст в `nm`

```
0000000000000000 V extext
```

И всё будет успешно работать.